# AWS S3 Bucket Policy Limit GETs to a set of IPs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I currently have a bucket named mets-logos. It has this bucket policy currently, which allows GetObjects from anyone.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mets-logos/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I wish to only allow GetObjects from a whitelist of IPs. Here is what I tried, but it does not work (outside IP's can still get objects)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mets-logos/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "100.77.17.80/32",
                        "100.77.26.210/32",
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Side question: If my bucket policy is correct, do I need to wait for AWS to reflect this change, or should it be reflected immediately?

Comment: Are you trying to block a range or just those 2 IP's?

Comment: I want to allow ONLY for those 2 IP's. Nobody else

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a Deny, along with exceptions, like this:

```
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Id":"S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement":
    [
        {
            "Sid"      : "IPAllow",
            "Effect"   : "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action"   : "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource" : "arn:aws:s3:::mets-logos/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress"   : {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                },
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "100.77.17.80/32"
                },
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "100.77.26.210/32"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This explicitly denies access to all IP addresses but allows the two addresses that you are whitelisting to perform `GetObject`.

I can see how this would be useful if you are accessing S3 under IAM credentials but you want to further control access at the bucket level. The `Deny` in this policy will override existing IAM user policies.

---

To answer your side question, policy changes take effect immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Access to S3 buckets is governed by both the S3 bucket policy and the IAM access policies that are attached to the principals accessing the bucket.

So it's possible that an IAM access policy may "overrule" an S3 bucket policy.

Your S3 bucket policy says "allow get if the IP is such-and-such". But there's nothing in the bucket policy that's saying "don't allow anyone else".

If your IAM user/role that's accessing the bucket allows `s3:GetObject` on your bucket (or `*`), then that policy lets them access the bucket.

If the IAM user/role does not have an explicit "allow" for "s3:GetObject" (or "s3:*"), then your policy would work.

To prevent users/roles that would otherwise be permitted access to the bucket, to be restricted to the IP addresses, then you need to change your policy to "deny" anyone NOT in an allowed IP address. An explicit "deny" in the bucket policy would overrule any "allow" in the IAM user/role's policy.

Try this policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyAllButFromAllowedIp",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mets-logos/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "100.77.17.80/32",
                        "100.77.26.210/32",
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```